# how to adjust line number in textfile using java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, file-io, text-files

how to adjust line number in textfile using java?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good so far.

I suggest you do what you are trying to achieve: you basically renumber each line.

1. You should introduce a variable, set it to an initial number (1,
   based on your example).
2. You use the new number when writing it out
   to the file.
3. You increment the variable.

I am intentionally not posting the exact code for you to improve. Comment if you need more help.

Comment: Might want to add that it's unnecessary to parse the entire line. Just find the first `:` (using `indexOf()`) and replace the number before that with the new increasing number (using `substring()`).

Comment: where will I set the initial number?

Comment: @emem: Wherever you want.

A good idea might be right before the loop.

Comment: @Andreas: it depends on the goal to be achieved. If you are looking for performance, your suggestion is a way to go. My idea was to go for an "easiest" solution or one that utilizes most of the given source.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you so much for your help! I did it!! Thanks for your wonderful suggestion

Comment: @quasatillis Agree on the "utilizes most of the given source", but disagree on "easiest" as in simplest code.

Comment: @Andreas: I could say we agree to disagree, but now this has raised my attention. On the "easiest" part: we would need to know how a/the programmer thinks about the problem/task itself. (As if he treats the input as a "table" (for which I would go with the solution sketch I provided), but if he treats the input as "text", then it is yours hands down).

Comment: @quasatillis The code will fail if there is not *exactly* 9 values. It's actually failing even with 9 values, because OP added a `+" ::"` to the end. If the code should be validating, parsing is correct, but then it should be doing some actual validation too, because as-is, it'll die with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for <9 values and silently drop extra values for >9 values. Since there's no stated goal of validating, a text replace is simpler and less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void filterSpecifiedLine(String skipLine) throws IOException {
        List<String[]> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("./Phonebook.txt"))
                .map(l -> l.split("::"))
                .filter(s -> !s[0].equals(skipLine))
                .map(s -> Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 1, s.length))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> generated = IntStream.range(0, lines.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> (i + 1) + "::" + String.join("::", lines.get(i)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Files.write(Paths.get("./Phonebook1.txt"), generated);
}
```

I have used ***Stream*** to come true a simplify version.

Comment: +1 Most advanced answer so far, though java 8 might just go too far; maybe the target is Android. Comment a bit though: the error reading and writing on the same file. Explanation of what happens.

Comment: Not that it likely matters in this case, but the streaming in OP code can handle unlimited file size, while this code will run out of memory if file is too big. Also, OP is not asking to *do* the delete, but instead is asking how to renumber if a line has *already* been deleted. Down-vote for not answering the question.